# regex javascript like mustache but leaving single } alone

Tags: javascript, regex

So, at this point I've been using this regex :  `/{{\s?([^}}]*)\s?}}/g`

Everything runs smoothly until I face something like `{{ } }}`.

How could I adapt the above regex to still match this situation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `[^}}]` doesn't do what you think it does (it's basically "not } and not }"). But try `{{\s?(.*?)\s?}}`

Comment: Use a parser instead.

Comment: @JaredSmith: Regex module *is* a text parser. One should use it wisely in order not to get into trouble, that is all.

Comment: @stribizhev yes, but its a *dumb* (as in simple) one. If you need to keep track of state (like nested sets of matched characters that you care about) then it is arguably the wrong one.

Comment: @JaredSmith: If I need to keep track of state, I use XRegExp in JS (well, it has a limited support for recursive matching), or .NET/PCRE/Python PyPi regex modules that support recursion/balanced constructs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an [unroll-the-loop technique](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop):

```
/{{\s*([^}]*(?:}(?!})[^}]*)*)}}/g
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hD9oI7/1)

It is basically the same as [`/{{\s*([^]*?)}}/g`](https://regex101.com/r/hD9oI7/2), but more efficient.

*Regex explanation:*

- `{{` - two literal `{{`
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespace (in order to "left-trim" the submatch)
- `([^}]*(?:}(?!})[^}]*)*)` - Capture group 1 matching zero or more sequences of...

  - `[^}]*` - zero or more characters other than `}` followed by zero or more sequences of...

    - `}(?!})` - a literal `}` not followed by a `}`
    - `[^}]*` - zero or more characters other than `}`
- `}}` - two literal `}`.

Comment: Awesome answer, I wouldn't come up with this one even in a lifetime.

Comment: There is one problem that also exists in your regex: the whitespace before `}}` will also be captured. Just right-trim the `match[1]` value (say, with `.replace(/\s+$/g, '')`).

Comment: @pravdomil: See [this JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rLku5yht/). `trim()` will do.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, is there any chance to do rtrim in regex?

Comment: @pravdomil: It will make the regex matching a bit slower: `/{{\s*([^}]*(?:}(?!})[^}]*?)*)\s*}}/g`